# Weird Error in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ubuntu-14.04

I'm writing a program in **python** using **OpenCV** which detects the edges (Canny Edge Detector) from the footage my webcam records. I'm also using two track-bars in order to control the threshold values (in order for to understand how these values change the output of this edge detector).

The code I wrote is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def nothing(x):
    pass

img = np.zeros((300,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('cannyEdge')
cv2.createTrackbar("minVal", "cannyEdge", 0,100, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("maxVal", "cannyEdge", 100,200,nothing)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):

    minVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos("minVal", "cannyEdge")
    maxVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos("maxVal", "cannyEdge")

    #capture frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    edge = cv2.Canny(frame,minVal,maxVal)

    #display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', edge)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

#When everything is done, release the capture
cap.release
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This program is for educational purposes only as I'm currently learning to use OpenCV.

Every time I run the program above the code seems to be working just fine but I get the following Error:

**GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed**

I've searched for the reason this error occurs but I haven't found anything helpful. My instinct tells me that my implementation for the trackbars is wrong and thus it's causing this error.

The tutorials I used are the following:

- [OpenCV tutorials - Canny Edge Detector](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html#canny)
- [OpenCV tutorials - Trackbars](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#trackbar)

Does anybody know why this error occurs? Any help will be appreciated!

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, OpenCV 3.2.0 and Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the track bars and displaying the image in the same window and see if the error persists. I bet it shouldn't. Change:  cv2.imshow('cannyEdge', edge)

Comment: I did what you proposed (make the trackbars and displaying the img in the same window) and it solved the problem. You have my thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you created another window named "frame"? If not, it looks like you should change 'frame' to 'cannyEdge':

```
cv2.imshow('cannyEdge', frame)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although you are absolutely right I have to give the right answer to I.Newton because he proposed the same thing (with different words) a little earlier than you. Have a nice day!!